# Find $B=\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{3\alpha}{2}$ if $\tan\alpha=\sqrt2$ and $\alpha\in(0^\circ;90^\circ).$

Tags: trigonometry

Find $B=\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\cos\dfrac{3\alpha}{2}$ if $\tan\alpha=\sqrt2$ and $\alpha\in(0^\circ;90^\circ).$

My try: $$\tan\alpha=\sqrt2=\dfrac{2\tan\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}{1-\tan^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}\\\sqrt2\tan^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}+2\tan\dfrac{\alpha}{2}-\sqrt2=0$$ from where $$\left(\tan\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)_{1,2}=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}$$ The calculations from here won't be easy. Is there another (presumably better) approach?

Comment: Use identities to express $B$ in terms of $\cos(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\alpha)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\cos\left(3\cdot\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) &= 4\cos^3\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - 3\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\\
\therefore \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{3\alpha}{2}\right) & = \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\left(4\cos^3\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - 3\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\left(4\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - 3\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{1 + \cos(\alpha)}{2}\right)\left(4\left(\frac{1 + \cos(\alpha)}{2}\right) - 3\right)\\
& = \left(\frac{1 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{2}\right)\left(4\left(\frac{1 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{2}\right) - 3\right)\\
& = \boxed{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{6}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand $B=(\cos\alpha+2\cos^2\alpha-1)/2$.
On the other hand, since $\sin\alpha=\sqrt2\cos\alpha$ and $\sin^2\alpha=1-\cos^2\alpha$ it follows that $\cos^2\alpha=1/3$ or $\cos\alpha=\sqrt3/3$ (given that $0\leq\alpha\leq90^\circ$). And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\cos(x)\cos(y)=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y))$$
To get
$$\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2\alpha)+\cos(\alpha))\tag{1}$$
in your case.
Now create a right triangle with angle $\alpha$ such that the side opposite is of length $\sqrt{2}$ and adjacent side is length $1$. Thus hypotenuse is $\sqrt{3}$. Thus $\cos(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Expand the $\cos(2\alpha)=2\cos^2(\alpha)-1$ in $(1)$ and plug to get,
$$B=\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{6}$$

This is just 1 of the many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Use the following identities:

- $\tan^2(\theta) + 1 = \sec^2(\theta).$
- $\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta) - 1.$
- $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta).$

Let $\theta = (\alpha/2).$

What is being requested is $\cos(\theta) \times \cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^4(\theta) - 3\cos^2(\theta).$

Then $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{\cos^2(2\theta)} = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\alpha)} = \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2 + 1 = 3.$

Therefore, $\displaystyle\cos(2\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$

Therefore, $~\displaystyle \cos^2(\theta) = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + 1}{2} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}.$

Therefore, $~\displaystyle \cos^4(\theta) = \frac{4 + 2\sqrt{3}}{12} = \frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{6}.$

---

So,

$$\cos(\theta) \times \cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^4(\theta) - 3\cos^2(\theta)$$

$$= ~\left[4 \times \frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{6}\right] - \left[3 \times \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}\right] $$

$$= ~\left[\frac{8 + 4\sqrt{3}}{6}\right] - \left[\frac{3 + 3\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}\right]. $$

Using the common denominator of $6\sqrt{3}$, this equals

$$= ~\left[\frac{8\sqrt{3} + 12}{6\sqrt{3}}\right] - \left[\frac{9 + 9\sqrt{3}}{6\sqrt{3}}\right] = \frac{3 - \sqrt{3}}{6\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{6}. $$